Which log-likelihood is to be maximized for left-truncated count data?
What is to be done, if the count data is missing the counts on the zeros (i.e. left truncated data)? Say one wants to estimate a Poisson regression and the goal is to derive the log-likelihood to be maximized.
My approach:
$$
f(y_i \mid y_i > 0, x_i) = \frac{f(y_i \mid x_i)}{1 - f(y_i = 0 \mid x_i)}
$$
$$
f(y_i \mid y_i > 0, x_i) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x_i}}{x_i! \left(1 - e^{-\lambda}\right)}
$$
The likelihood function to be maximized is:
$$
L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x_i}}{x_i! \left(1 - e^{-\lambda}\right)}
$$
The log-likelihood function is:
$$
\log L(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(-\lambda + x_i \log(\lambda) - \log(x_i!) - \log\left(1 - e^{-\lambda}\right)\right)
$$

Your question is ambiguous because "missing the counts" sounds like censored data, not truncated data.  Which do you mean?  Your analysis is for truncated data -- but you don't ask any specific question.  "Any input" is not an appropriate question for this site.

You describe a valid conditional log-likelihood that describes a pure Poisson generation mechanism with zero-suppression. Is that what you mean?  As @whuber points out, if you clarify the motivation for zero-suppression -- and thereby the mechanism of zero-generation -- then the model can be written more accurately. For instance, if you have a 2-step process: flip a coin. With probability $p \ll 1$ generate a Poisson random number; else generate a 0. That's a different model (with parameters $p$ and $\lambda$, and a much bigger need to suppress zeros, and a different log-likelihood.

Thanks Peter, that's exactly what I wanted to ask. I think in my case this basic likelihood will do it. You are referring to a more difficult set-up like zero-inflation or hurdle right?
